# strange cvSaveImage behavior

Tags: opencv

i have recently started using opencv and this one has baffled me.

```
void saveImageSnippet(char *imageName, int height, int width, void* data, int nChannels) //data is char[height * width]
{
    char fName[200]="c:\\testimg\\";
    FILE *fptr;
    IplImage *img;
    sprintf(fName,"%s%s.bmp",fName,imageName);  
    img = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(width, height),8/*depth*/,nChannels);
    img->imageData=(unsigned char*)data;
    cvSaveImage(fName, img); //Unhandled exception 
    cvReleaseImage(&img);   
}
```

At cvSaveImage : Unhandled exception at 0x6e8e871d in vc2008_1x.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x745c3a63.
Is there anything i am not doing right?

now an interesting part,
if i add a couple of unused variables, cvSaveImage works just fine

```
void saveImageSnippet(char *imageName, int height, int width, void* data, int nChannels) 
{
   int var1, var2; //unused variables
    char fName[200]="c:\\testimg\\";
    FILE *fptr;
    IplImage *img;
    sprintf(fName,"%s%s.bmp",fName,imageName);  
    img = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(width, height),8/*depth*/,nChannels);
    img->imageData=(unsigned char*)data;
    cvSaveImage(fName, img); //now it works fine
    cvReleaseImage(&img);   
}
```

Comment: please avoid the deprecated c-api. no new code should be written using that.

Answer (score 0):

please use opencv's c++ api, 
 avoid anything, that has iplimages in it (especially here on SO !)

```
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp" // no, *not* highgui.h !

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    string fName = format("c:\\testimg\\%s.bmp",imageName);

    Mat img = imread( fName );
    if ( img.empty() )
         return -1;
         // your image was not loaded

    imsave(fName);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, given an option one would do that. But i am working on a fairly complex C code developed over the years (from opencv 2.1 days). So, for now, i have to make do with what i have got. Any idea why this anomaly?